# Why does the resistor have a straight line?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, circuitikz

I'm making the next circuit:

[image]
based on the next one
[image]
but the resistor has a straight line across. I understand that I am giving the command but I don't understand where.

And by the way, can someone please explain how to work with the nodes, the lines, the cursors, etc? It takes me a lot of work to have done codes like this and perhaps I don't fully grasp if this is working because it's correct or by luck.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{circuitikz} \draw
 (0,0) node[anchor=east]{$v^{-}_{N}$}
  to[short, o-*] (1,0)
  to[R, l=$R_I$, *-*] (1,2)
  %to [R, v=$v_x$, l=$10\ohm$] (3,2)
 % to[short] (4,2) to[cV, i=$\frac{\siemens}{5}v_x$, *-*] (4,0)
 %  to[short] (3,0) to[R, l=$5\ohm$, *-*] (3,2)

% (3,0) -- (1,0)
 (1,2) to[short, o-*] (0,2)
  node[anchor=east]{$v^{+}_{P}$}
 (3,1) node[anchor=east,xshift=3cm]{$v_O$}  to[R,l=$R_O$, ] (3.5,1) 
  to[short,] (2,1) to[cV, i=$\frac{}{}v_x$, o-] (2,-1) -- (2,-1) node [] {}
 
%  to[short, -] (2,-1)
% (2,0) node [-] {}
  to node[ground]{}(2,-0.5)







;
%    \draw  (2,1) -- node[sloped,currarrow,pos=1] {}  (3,1) ;
\end{circuitikz}



\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, I really advise reading the tutorials in the circuitikz manual (in the tutorial introduction,  you'll find a pointer to the tutorials/sections you need to read of the Ti*k*Z manual). In your code, there are lots of things that are not  correct or equivalent to doing nothing (like `(2,-1) -- (2,-1) node [] {}`).

Comment: Never nest `tikzpicture` environments like you do (`circuitikz` environment is the same as `tikzpicture`, and in a standalone you have to use the latter). You will get ll the bounding boxes (picture margins) completely off.

Comment: Finally, the wire overwriting your resistor is because this: `(3,1) to[R,l=$R_O$, ] (3.5,1) 
  to[short,] (2,1) `: you ask to put a resistor in a 0.5cm spot (it will not fit, you need at least 1.5cm with default sizes) and then you draw a line through right to left.

Comment: @Rmano, great advise, thanks; indeed , I have checked the manual and see somethings were unadecuated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the first image:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3.14]{standalone}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz} 
\draw   (0,0)   node[left]  {$v^{-}_{N}$}
                to [short,  o-*] ++ ( 1,0) coordinate (aux)
                to [R=$R_I$, -*] ++ ( 0,2)
                to [short,   -*] ++ (-1,0)
                node[left]  {$v^{+}_{P}$}
        (aux)   ++ (3,1)  node[right] {$v_o$}
                to [R,a=$R_0$,o-]++ (-2,0)
                to [cV, l=$v_x$] ++ (0,-2) ++ (0,0.4)
                node[ground]{};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

*Note*: I didn't investigate, why you have line over resistor. Apparently you draw it. Your code is unnecessary complicated (to me), so it was simpler that I redraw circuit from scratch.

It is not clear, if you like to get a solution for the second image too. From above solution to it is quite simple way: by use of `fit` library you can draw triangle in the background of above image.

**Edit:**
Code for image should be self-explanatory :-).

Circuit is drawn in two loops. Coordinate for dipoles are determined relatively to beginning of loops (`(0,0)` for input and (`aux`) for output) using syntax  determined in `tikz` (on which `circuitikz` is based) `++`. For example `\draw (0,0) to [short, o-*] ++ (1,0)` means draw line form `(0,0)` to the right for 1cm with circle on beginning of line and black circle on the end, and `(aux) ++ (3,1)` is determined a coordinate, which is apart from `aux` for 3cm to left and 1cm above.

For more details see `Ti*k*Z & PGF manual (v3.1.9a), section *13.4 Relative and Incremental Coordinates*, page 146.

**Edit (1)**: Improved MWE: added output voltage $v_o$.
**Edit (2)**: Considered @Rmano comment.

Comment: Thanks I would like to be explained about the draw command, how to use it with the node, the lines, the -- or ++ operators, I dont understand quite well.

Comment: @riccs_0x, see edited answer. To make you more familiar with drawing circuits, I recommend to read documentations for packages `circuitikz` (relative short) and for Ti*k*Z (which is huge, so for start should sufficient to read the first tutorial and content of part III,

Comment: Thanks again, Im starting to study how to draw and make nodes from scratch too.

Comment: I think in  the last line of code  `++(0,0.5)`  can be safely deleted

Comment: @jsbibra, you are right. It is there that ground is closer to voltage source.